# Update status of dynamically created checkboxes in jquery by value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am getting back an array of checkbox values from a separate function. These values need to be passed to a separate function which matches all values with existing checkboxes on the page and checks the ones that match what has been passed on to the function.

My checkboxes are created on my form but he problem now is I am unable to set their check status to true.

The values that are passed to my function are ["ChecboxValue1","CheckboxValue2"]
My code looks something like this:

```
function select_worksheet_checkboxes(selected_worksheet_json){
    var worskeheet_object = jQuery.parseJSON(selected_worksheet_json);

    $.each(worskeheet_object, function(worksheet_key,worksheet_value) {


    });
}
```

What I need is code that would go in the each segment and update all the check boxes. I have tried `("input:checkbox[value=worksheet_value]").attr("checked","true");` but didn't have any success.

My check boxes are on a modal, that doesn't seem to be the problem since all my other controls (select2, textboxes and icheck) get updated.

The checkboxes on this page are based on [Smart Forms](http://doptiq.com/smart-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `$.each('selector', function(idx, obj))`.

Ther first parameter is a collection. The second is a function, where in the function, the first parameter is the index, the second is the object.

The second parameter is not a value, that is an object.

So check this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
```

Script

```
var collection = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
console.log(collection);
$.each(collection, function(idx, obj) {
    $(obj).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: How does this know which checkboxes are passed to be checked? It seems to me like this tries to go over all checkboxes and check them. I only want to check the ones that have been passed as a json string to the function.

By the way the length of collection is 0. Shouldn't that have the total number of check boxes on my page?

Comment: I've just try to point on that, that the 2nd param of function is an object, not a value.

Comment: check the `$(obj).val() == 'value_what_you_want'`